# angular ionic app forces dark mode in mobile

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, darkmode

I have an angular ionic app which works fine with dark and light mode in web browser but in mobile build, it forces dark mode.
I tried the following also:

```
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light" />
```

*ionic version: 6.1.2